# Programatically access Google Sites content

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I need to scrape the content of a Google site that I own but can't pass the Google identity authentication layer

To do so, I created a Service Account in my Google Cloud console and added it to my workspace Domain Wide Delegation with following scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sites

I used the following code to generate a JWT token and pass it as a Authorization Bearer to a get request.
Parameters used:

- host => the google site url
- audience => https://sites.google.com (not sure what this is ...)
- sa_path => path to my service account json key
- sa_email => my service account email

Code Extract:

```py
    import argparse
    import time
    
    import google.auth.crypt
    import google.auth.jwt

    
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    
    import requests
    
    
    def generate_jwt(
        sa_keyfile,
        sa_email="account@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        audience="your-service-name",
        expiry_length=3600,
    ):
        """Generates a signed JSON Web Token using a Google API Service Account."""
    
        now = int(time.time())
    
        # build payload
        payload = {
            "iat": now,
            # expires after 'expiry_length' seconds.
            "exp": now + expiry_length,
            # iss must match 'issuer' in the security configuration in your
            # swagger spec (e.g. service account email). It can be any string.
            "iss": sa_email,
            # aud must be either your Endpoints service name, or match the value
            # specified as the 'x-google-audience' in the OpenAPI document.
            "aud": audience,
            # sub and email should match the service account's email address
            "sub": sa_email,
            "email": sa_email,
        }
    
        # sign with keyfile
        signer = google.auth.crypt.RSASigner.from_service_account_file(sa_keyfile)
        jwt = google.auth.jwt.encode(signer, payload)
    
        return jwt
    
    
    def make_jwt_request(signed_jwt, url="https://my-google-site"):
        """Makes an authorized request to the endpoint"""
        headers = {
            "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(signed_jwt.decode("utf-8")),
        }
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        html = response.content.decode("utf-8")
        # print(response.status_code, response.content)
        response.raise_for_status()
    
        clean_html =remove_tags(html)
        print(clean_html)
    
    
    # Function to remove tags
    def remove_tags(html):
     
        # parse html content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
     
        for data in soup(['style', 'script']):
            # Remove tags
            data.decompose()
     
        # return data by retrieving the tag content
        return ' '.join(soup.stripped_strings)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description=__doc__, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            "host", help="Your API host, e.g. https://your-project.appspot.com."
        )
        parser.add_argument("audience", help="The aud entry for the JWT")
        parser.add_argument("sa_path", help="The path to your service account jsonfile.")
        parser.add_argument("sa_email", help="The email address for the SA.")
    
        args = parser.parse_args()
    
        expiry_length = 3600
        keyfile_jwt = generate_jwt(
            args.sa_path, args.sa_email, args.audience, expiry_length
        )
    
        print("Making request...")
        make_jwt_request(keyfile_jwt, args.host)
```

The Auth part is not working =>  I'm getting the Google Signin page as a response

Answer (score 1):

Found a  degraded solution for that: using the Drive API with the export method

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']


service_account_json_key = '/usr/local/google/home/scaucheteux/Devs/keys/sca-genai-misc-gsite.json'
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        filename=service_account_json_key,
        scopes=scope)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)


# Call the Drive v3 API
request = service.files().export(fileId='<SiteID',mimeType='text/plain').execute()
    
print(request.decode('utf-8'))
```

This gets the text portions of your site but:

- export limited to 10mb
- only draft version is exported, not the currently published version
- no links, images etc ...